# laravel 7 dynamically show input based on selected value

Tags: php, laravel, include, laravel-blade

I have a list of contact groups, each one of these groups may have a segment list or not, I need to show the segment input if the user selects the group that has a segment.
There is an if statement to conditionally show the segment input but it only works after I go to the next step and go back, how can I achieve this and show the segment input immediately after the user selects the group that has a segment?

here's my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 list_select_box" target-box="segments-select-box" segments-url="{{ action('SegmentController@selectBox') }}">
                @include('helpers.form_control', [
                'name' => 'lists_segments[' . $index . '][mail_list_uid]',
                'include_blank' => trans('messages.choose'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'label' => trans('messages.which_list_send'),
                'value' => (is_object($lists_segment_group['list']) ? $lists_segment_group['list']->uid : ""),
                'options' => Auth::user()->customer->readCache('MailListSelectOptions', []),
                'rules' => isset($rules) ? $rules : []
                ])
        </div>

        @if (is_object($lists_segment_group['list']) && collect($lists_segment_group['list']->readCache('SegmentSelectOptions', []))->count())
        <div class="col-md-5 segments-select-box multiple">
            @include('helpers.form_control', [
            'value' => implode(",", $lists_segment_group['segment_uids']),
            'type' => 'select',
            'name' => 'lists_segments[' . $index . '][segment_uids][]',
            'label' => trans('messages.which_segment_send'),
            'options' => collect($lists_segment_group['list']->readCache('SegmentSelectOptions', [])),
            'multiple' => true,
            'quick_note' => trans('messages.leave_empty_to_choose_all_list')
            ])
        </div>
        @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use java-script or jQuery, hope this jquery plugin:  [dkeeghan /
jQuery-doWhen](https://github.com/dkeeghan/jQuery-doWhen)  would help